# sitecore query items by client url

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am looking for a quick and dirty way to query the layouts files of a particular page by its friendly url.  This is probably easy, but I can't find the solution.

Basically I want to say something like the following.  Pseudo-code:

```
var mainpage = Sitecore.EasyQueryUtility.GetItemByFriendlyUrl(requestedUrl);
```

or

```
var mainpage = Sitecore.EasyQueryUtility.GetOppositeOfFriendlyUrl(friendlyurl);
```

Comment: What do you expect to get in `mainpage`? Content item behind the URL? Layout definition item?

Comment: probably the path to the `.aspx` file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do two things here:

1. Determine an item based on its rendered URL in the address bar (i.e. friendly URL)
2. Determine the layout being used by the item once you determine the item.

If those are correct, hopefully this can help you out:

**Note**: untested code I did on-the-fly

```
// if you have the full URL with protocol and host
public static Item GetItemFromUrl(string url)
{
    string path = new Uri(url).PathAndQuery;    
    return GetItemFromPath(path);
}

// if you have just the path after the hostname
public static Item GetItemFromPath(string path)
{
    // remove query string
    if(path.Contains("?"))
        path = path.split('?')[0];

    path = path.Replace(".aspx", "");

    return Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(path);
}
```

Once you have the item you can get the layout's name like so:

```
item.Visualization.GetLayout(Sitecore.Context.Device).Name;
```

Or the layout's physical file path to the ASPX:

```
item.Visualization.GetLayout(Sitecore.Context.Device).FilePath;
```

Comment: yeah, i actually just have to modify the path to change the various hostnames to the content path and then query

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the path of the aspx file which is used for the layout of your page, you can use:

```
Sitecore.Context.Item.Visualization.Layout.FilePath
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood you but if you want to control the format of friendly URLs you can set several attributes via the Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions class and pass an instance of this in to the link manager.  See [here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc62keywords/dynamic_links_sc62_a4.pdf) for more details.  (Note - the LinkManager class is only available from SiteCore 6 I beleive).

The code you would end up with looks like this:

```
Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions urlOptions = (Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions)Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions.DefaultOptions.Clone(); 
urlOptions.SiteResolving = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.Rendering.SiteResolving; 
string url = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, urlOptions);
```

You can then set fields like AddAspxExtension on the urlOptions you pass in.

As you can see, the process is reliant on you passing in an item - whether it be obtained via the current context or retrieved from the URL you start off with.

If you were asking about obtaining the layout definition item, take a look at [this](http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/Developers/Articles/2011/07/Programmatically-set-layout-in-sitecore.aspx) which shows you how.